# Slow VideoCapture with rpi camera in raspbian with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, raspbian, face-recognition

i'm making a face/eyes recognition software with python, using the opecv library, in a Raspberry and capturing the video with a rpi camera.
I've already written the code, and everything works fine on my PC. Actually it works fine on my Raspberry as well, but the problem is about the speed of it. On my Raspberry it goes really slow.
Here's the code anyway:

```
#import numpy as np
import cv2

dims = (240, 120) # webcam dimensions
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 360);
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/Desktop/Raspberry/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/Desktop/Raspberry/haarcascade_eye.xml')

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #frame = cv2.imread('./Data/viola.jpg')
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect the face
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    print(len(faces))
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As you can see i've set the resolution to 640X480, and with this the video shows about one frame every 1-2 seconds. If i don't specify the resolution it gets me a really small window in where there's my output. I have to say that i connect to my Raspberry throw SSH, but even if i record the video, and then i watch it on my PC is very slow. What i want to say is that it doesn't seem a problem given by the SSH tunnel.
To use the opencv's VideoCapture feature i had to inslall the UV4L driver, following this guide: http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14 .
I saw many people using this method of capturing a video with opencv in raspberry, and nobody say anything about the framerate. Anyone know what should i do to have it faster?
PS i know that may be this is not the place in where we can make questions like this. But i don't really know where to ask it.

Comment: Grabbing video and streaming it with a Raspberry Pi can be done with a reasonable framerate at your resolution. Actually performing face detection requires a lot more processing power so less than 1 FPS is not out of the ordinary...

Comment: Actually it's really slow even if i just capture the frame and i show it. So may be it's not about performing face detection. I think it's something else.

Comment: How do you watch the video? You use something like VNC? That can also slow down a system. You can check if it is in any way the network load by not using `imshow` but just writing the FPS to a text file every x number of frames

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing the uncompressed frames, set this property to capture compressed frames, `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))`

**ex:**

```
#import numpy as np
import cv2

dims = (240, 120) # webcam dimensions
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 360)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
.......
```